# trying different Xpaths none of them work

Tags: html, css, xml, xpath, google-sheets-formula

My aim is to import the score from https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/amzn/stock-analysis, as you can see the score here is "10" shown in the Octagon image and this score is different for different companies for example https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/roku/stock-analysis has a score of "5".

When I inspect the element I see:

<text y="100" dy="0.32em"><tspan x="100" text-anchor="middle">10</tspan></text>

So I am using googledocs and Importxml function and I have tried so many different Xpaths but all return #N/A

I have tried the following as xpath:

//tspan

//tspan[1]

//text/tspan[1]

//text[1]/tspan[1]

//svg/text[1]/tspan[1]

I have even tried entering the full xpath

/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div/article/div[2]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/svg/text/tspan

Please can someone guide where I am going wrong.

The function I am running on google docs is:

=IMPORTXML(A1,A2)

Where A1 is https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/amzn/stock-analysis
and A2 is one of the xpaths mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

These xpath will work for you

```
//*[@text-anchor='middle']
```

or

```
//*[@x='100']
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work with `Google Sheets` since the website uses `Javascript` to display the data. You can use `Selenium` to scrape this or similar tools.

If you really want to do this with GS, you can use [ImportfromWeb](https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/) addon(number of requests are limited in the free plan). You have to specify to use `jsrendering.

The following XPath will select what you're looking for :

```
//div[contains(@class,"active")]/span
```

Formula in C6 :

```
=IMPORTFROMWEB(C2;C3;B4:C4)
```

Output :

[image: IFW]